# drawable-xxhdpi folder not created in Eclipse by ADT plugin

Tags: android

Creating a new Android application project in the latest Eclipse Luna(4.4.0) with the latest ADT plugin(23.0.2.1259578) is not automatically creating a `res/drawable-xxhdpi` folder, although the other folders(drawable, drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi ) are created.

Is that expected? If i remember correctly, the previous ADT version did create it. Are `xxhdpi` screens no longer supported or something?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it has something to do with your API settings, but either way, it's not a problem, xxhdpi screens are still supported and you can create the folder yourself, just like you can with any other identifier.

You can also create any other size / density folder s yourself and ADT will automatically recognise them. Take a look at this link:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: The link does not mention `xxhdpi`.

Comment: It's not one of the standard sizes, but you can still use it, you can combine any identifier with android folder, for instance: values-xxhdpi, values-si (language), values-land (landscape) etc... Same goes for drawable folders, and any others.

Answer (score 0):

- ***I think you are using XHDPI graphics because the emulator is
  emulating an XHDPI device.***

---

```
public static final int DENSITY_XXHIGH
```

Added in API level 16

---

### {EDIT}

As i posted `API-16` must be the `minimum-sdk`

***I have tested it***

### ***You can notice in the second snapshot the `xxhdpi` was automatically generated with the project creation and i didn't manually create it***

**Settings**::
[image]

***Structure***::

[image]

Comment: Emulator definitions should have no effect on project creation.

Comment: @faizal ... Check the edit ... I think this solves your question !

Comment: it does not work for me. What version of ADT are you on?

Comment: @faizal ...... I have the ADT-Version:: `Version:22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508` ...... Double check the minimum-sdk when you are starting the project !

Comment: This implies the problem is with the ADT version.

Comment: @faizal ... May be .... I have not tested that ! .... If even it does not have it  you can manually add it .... ( `Hope my answer was what you were looking for in your question` ) !

Comment: I was looking for an explanation on the reason for this behaviour with the new ADT.